# JavaFX8 - Tabs with separate FXML and controllers

Tags: java, controller, tabs, javafx-8

I'm trying to include FXML files in the tabs of my mainview.fxml and for those I would like to use different controllers. I did this a year ago and it worked, but when I tried it again my other controllers are all null, except the main one.

This is my code for the mainframe controller:

```
public class MainFrameController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainFrameController.class);
    protected ServiceInterface service;
    protected Stage primaryStage;
    protected Stage stage;
    protected MODE mode;

    @FXML
    private BoxFrameController boxFrameController;

    @FXML
    private ReservationFrameController reservationFrameController;

    @FXML
    private TabPane tabPane;

    @FXML
    private Tab boxTab;

    private void loadTestData() {
        LOGGER.info("GUI: Loading test data");
        try {
            service.loadTestData();
            boxFrameController.setService(service);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void setPrimaryStage(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
//boxFrameController.setPrimaryStage(primaryStage);
    }

    public void setStage(Stage stage) {
        this.stage = stage;
    }

    public void setMODE(MODE mode) {
        this.mode = mode;
    }

    public void setService (ServiceInterface service) throws ServiceException {
        this.service = service;
//setup controllers to switch tabs
        boxFrameController.setService(service);
//boxFrameController.fillTable(service);
//reservationFrameController.setService(this.service);
    }
}
```

Here is my MainFrame.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sepm.ss17.e1326220.gui.MainFrameController">
    <children>
        <VBox layoutX="-1.0" layoutY="-1.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <children>
                <MenuBar>
                    <menus>
                        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                            <items>
                                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
                            </items>
                        </Menu>
                        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
                            <items>
                                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                            </items>
                        </Menu>
                    </menus>
                </MenuBar>
                <TabPane fx:id="tabPane" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
                    <tabs>
                        <Tab fx:id="boxTab" closable="false" text="Boxes">
                            <content>
                                <fx:include fx:id="box" source="BoxFrame.fxml" />
                            </content>
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab closable="false" text="Reservations" />
                        <Tab closable="false" text="Invoices" />
                        <Tab closable="false" text="Statistic" />
                    </tabs>
                </TabPane>
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

In my BoxFrameController I have this:

```
public class BoxFrameController extends MainFrameController {

    private Stage stage;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BoxFrameController.class);


    @FXML
    public Button createButton;
    @FXML
    public Button editButton;
    @FXML
    public Button deleteButton;
    @FXML
    public Button searchButton;

    @FXML
    public TextField fromRateTextField, toRateTextField, fromAreaTextField, toAreaTextField, litterTextField;

    @FXML
    public CheckBox dailyRateCheckBox, areaCheckBox, litterCheckBox, isWindowedCheckBox, isSingleCheckBox;

    @FXML
    public ImageView WindowedImageView, SingleImageView, horseImageView;

    @FXML
    public Label fromRateLabel, toRateLabel, fromAreaLabel, toAreaLabel, litterLabel;

    @FXML
    public TableView tableView;

    @FXML
    public TableColumn rateColumn, areaColumn, litterColumn;

    public void fillTable(ServiceInterface service) throws ServiceException {
        tableView.refresh();
        try {
            List<Box> boxes = service.searchBoxesParameters(0,0,0,"",0,0,false,false);
            tableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(boxes));
            tableView.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
            tableView.refresh();
        } catch (ServiceException ex) {
            LOGGER.error(ex.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

And in my BoxFrame.fxml I have this line (think that should be enough):

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1001.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sepm.ss17.e1326220.gui.BoxFrameController">
```

With the debugger I found out that my boxFrameController in `setService()` of the MainFrameController is null and I just can't figure out why...

I'm using Scenebuilder for all of this and I also tried to look for a mistake there, but couldn't find it there aswell, so I was hoping that maybe one of you guys already knows this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the controller you have

```
@FXML
private BoxFrameController boxFrameController;
```

but in the FXML you have

```xml
<fx:include fx:id="box" source="BoxFrame.fxml" />
```

The rule for [nested controllers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers) is that the controller is injected into a field whose name is the `fx:id` concatenated with `"Controller"`, so your field should be

```
@FXML
private BoxFrameController boxController;
```

Comment: You Sir are a livesaver. My Controller now has a value and I finally can continue. Did not know that this id had anything to do with this. Thank you very much

Comment: @LoWesT How else would it know which controller you wanted it to inject...?

Comment: I actually thought it had something to do with Scenebuilder. Problem is I only did this once and even then I did not really know why it worked then